# How to pass hundreds of files from multiple subdirectories to cat?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a directory full of subdirectories and each subdirectory has some text files inside of them (i.e. depth is 1).

I'd like to cat all these files (in no particular order) into one file:

```
cat file1 file2.... fileN >new.txt
```

Is there a bash shell one-liner that could list all the files inside of these directories and pass them to cat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cat
```

`find` will recursively search for files (`-type f`) and print their names as null-terminated strings (`-print0`).

`xargs` will read null terminated strings (`-0`) from stdin and pass them as arguments to `cat`

Comment: @userunknown: Useless how? not all versions of `find` support `-exec command {} +`

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} \; > concatenated.txt
```

Granted it calls cat a bunch of times rather than just once, but the effect is the same.

Comment: You could use a plus sign instead of semicolon: `-exec cat {} +`. This will only invoke `cat` once, with all parameters - just like `xargs` does. Still, I tend to prefer `xargs` since it's very flexible.